# GPU usage nill during mining

Tags: gpu

Mining using claymores miner, amd rx400 series.
Most activity appears to be on the CPU and disk. Periodic spike on GPU graph.
I know it works, eth being deposited in wallet.
Is this normal?

Info comes from Task Manager, performance tab.
Is there a better way to see GPU activity?

Comment: Where are you getting this information from? In which program do you see this GPU graph? Maybe you can edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is normal. My other program that measures GPU activity says it is at max clock speed, and Nvidia Control Panel says my GPU is being used for my miner. I would recommend MSI Afterburner to see GPU activity, but any program would work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

AMD has a 1st Party monitoring tool that is described as:

> AMD System Monitor is a Processor (CPU), Graphic card (GPU) & Memory utilization tool that illustrates the different workloads of the CPU and GPU.
>   With the release of AMD’s new Accelerated Processing Units (APUs), this utility was designed to show the x86 and GPU make up of these new class of processors, and to depict the workload balance between GPU versus x86 that can be seen in today’s most recent applications.

It can be found at:

https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDSystemMonitor.aspx